# Associating a Project to Sonar in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

I have Eclipse Indigo 3.7 base with MyEclipse 10 Java enterprise development plug-in:

- I have installed Sonar plug-in for eclipse.
- Installed Sonar server and running it locally from localhost (localhost:9000)
- Tested the Server connection in Eclipse from
  Windows>Preferences>Sonar>Servers. Connection is successful.
- For my Project, ran the Maven goal for sonar (sonar:sonar). Build is 
  successful. I am able to browse the results in localhost. (localhost:9000)

My issue is with Associating the project to Sonar.
When i right click on my project, Configure > Associate with Sonar, I get a screen where nothing happens.

Basically the screen has 2 fields,Project and Sonar Project.
The Project field contains the name of my Project and Sonar Project field lists this message - "click here to start searching for a remote Sonar project"

- I click on that field and enter my groupid:artifactid but nothing
  happens.
- I also tried entering the Project Name listed in Sonar    dashboard
  but that also does not help.

When i right click on my project, In the context menu i am unable to see 'Sonar' option.

Help me associate my project to Sonar in eclipse. Please let me know what i am missing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Sonar are you using?

Comment: Hi Fabrice, I am using sonar-3.5.1

Comment: Is your project a multi-module project or a single module one? Do you have m2eclipse installed in your Eclipse?

Comment: Hi Fabrice, My project is a multi-module project. Basically it a Portal project so we have multiple portlets to handle different modules.

Comment: Hi Fabrice, The IDE i am using is a customized version provided by my organization which is basically Eclipse Indigo 3.7 base with MyEclipse installed.

Comment: OK, do you try to associate the root projet or the modules ?

Comment: Hi Fabrice, I am associating the root project from eclipse. I have created a Web Project in eclipse and added the portlet related jars. I am trying to associate this project to Sonar.

Comment: Hi Fabrice, Do you see any issues with the versions that i am using? I need to do a Local Analysis using Sonar. Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue with my Liferay project in Eclipse (liferay-plugins-sdk.6.2.0) and here is how I got it working:

- Install the eclipse plugin, and test server connection
- Install the Sonar server and start it (for example on `yourhost:9000`)
- Go to `yourhost:9000` and login (admin/admin unless you changed it)
- Go to Settings -> System -> Provisioning
- Create new project (`+Create` in the top right corner)
- I've used key=Liferay6.2 and name=liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0

After the above steps I went back to my eclipse project and in `Configure > Associate with Sonar` I was able to search/find the liferay project.

Comment: I have also faced this issue .. you have saved hours for me . Could you please let me know if I have Java project what <b>key</b>  and <b>name</b>  I have to use

Comment: I believe "key" is something custom and "name" is the name of your java project. I am not sure though, only tested with Liferay.

Answer (score 4):

When using Sonar Eclipse, you can associate Eclipse projects only to the corresponding Sonar modules (unless you are working on a single-module project, which is pretty rare in fact).

This means that you can't associate the root project (which is logical as by definition, a root project has no sources in Sonar). You have to right-click on all the imported Maven modules, and associate them all in a single run.

Comment: Hi Fabrice, I am not getting your explanation. I am having a single project which has java classes. It is a Maven project. I am able to run it from eclipse on the server using sonar:sonar and i am able to see the results. But i do not see any options in eclipse to do a local analysis. Please let me know if this is not possible to do.

Comment: Hi Fabrice, I had set the Local Analysis Properties for the project and now i am able to see the Sonar option in the menu. I am able to Associate a Project to Sonar. I changed the mode to Local. But when i select the Run Local Analysis option, in console i see EXECUTION SUCCESS message but nothing gets listed in the violations view. Please provide your inputs.

Comment: More Updates: I also tried to run sonar runner. Configured the sonar-project.properties. The execution is success when i run sonar-runner from command prompt of the project folder but i still do not see the violations in eclipse. Please help me to run the local analysis and see the violation in eclipse. Let me know what i am missing.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your project folder in eclipse workspace from the terminal and run following command:

```
 mvn sonar:sonar
```

This command will create your sonar project. Try associating the project again. Make sure you enter the name associated with your project from your
pom file. (Clear the text field)

Answer (score 2):

### BEST ANSWER AFTER SO MUCH ANALYSIS(I have faced the same problem)

1. Forget to add to associate with SonarQube first
2. If you want to add sonar group id create `sonar-project.properties`

Just add below code

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=javapractice
sonar.projectName=javapractice
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src

# Language
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

4. download sonnar-runner from github.
5. download sonar example from github
6. download sonar
7. run sonar as per your operating system from command prompt
8. go to sonar example path like `c:/sonar example/java/.. /.. *.properties` path (beside src)
9. run sonnar-runner `c:/.... / sonnar-runner.bat -e`
10. go to browser `http://localhost:9000` after that (login:`admin`/`admin`)
11. your project is displayed in the browser.

Comment: While slightly difficult to read, it actually worked for me and solved my similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Choose *Maven* on the project and then choose *Select Maven Profiles* and then choose *with-sonar* in Eclipse. This will enable the Sonar functionality on projects. Now you will see the *Sonar* option when you right click on projects.