# Associate with SonarQube not showing something in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm new in using sonar, please be patient if I write something wrong.

I'm trying to configure the sonarqube plugin in intellij (not the sonarqube Community plugin). I'm in the step where a particular project must be added into the analysis, by clicking over the project and selecting "Associate with SonarQube" in the contextual menu. This is described in the oficial documentation:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+in+IntelliJ

The problem is in the frame where my project should popup there is nothing there (the frame below):

http://docs.sonarqube.org/download/attachments/1441881/associate-with-sonarqube.png?version=2&modificationDate=1387448001000&api=v2&effects=drop-shadow

I'm not sure what is the problem. I'm using intellij 14.0.1 and my project is a Java maven2 project.

Any idea?

Comment: I've also encountered this issue. Connection tests successfully, but right click `Associate with SonarQube` showed nothing

Comment: why? It took so long that I dropped. So I haven't have the opporutnity to test it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in a state where you can't find your project to select. You can follow the similar steps like this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22304087/5715934

1) Install the Sonar server and start it (for example on yourhost:9000 or remote one)

2) Go to yourhost:9000 and login (admin/admin unless you changed it)

3)Go to Settings -> System -> Provisioning or simply http://yourhost:9000/projects

4)Create new project (+Create in the top right corner)

5)Give key= and name=

Then u can will be able to find your project when u enter the name when right-click -> 'associate with sonarQube' window. You can select that and click 'ok'.
Then You can start analyzing with right-click the project -> analuze -> inspect code.